# Copy from variable to variable

Tags: batch-file

For my batch file I need to do a few different things...I have completed steps 1-3

1) Perform a dir search and save the result of that search in a variable
2) Set the destination path as a variable
3) Copy the source file to the destination path

My code so far :

```
@echo off
cls
cd /d D:\Downloads\Videos
set "flshvid=&dir *flash*.mkv /s /b"
set "flshdir=O:\Aayush\Videos\TV Shows\The Flash\Season 3"
xcopy %flshvid% %flshdir%
```

Why doesn't this code work?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `dir /S *arrow*.avi`

Comment: run with `echo on` and you will see yourself.

Comment: @Stephan tried didn't work

Comment: I didn't claim that it would solve the problem - only that you can see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables may not start with a numeric because `%n` where `n` is 0..9 refers to the serial parameter number provided to the routine.

replace `1` and `2` with variable names that do not start with a numeric

Comment: thanks for your help that helped but still did not work in the end